# Understanding of @Autowired annotation over non-setter method

Tags: spring, autowired

Assume I have method:

```
@Autowired
public void doSomething(MyType t){
     System.out.println(t);
}
```

I just wonder does `@Autowired` means here that this method will be called and class initialized during spring config booting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring will initialize the MyType class on start up that will later be used by the doSomething method (assuming as well that the MyType class has been appropriately annotated as a spring component).

When the class that contains the doSomething(MyType t) method is initialized then MyType will be injected - which is not necessarily on Spring start up.

Comment: Tests that I held against this example doesn't meet what you are writing. I see that autowired method was called on startup, so it works like `init-method` from xml config, I guess

Comment: Yes that would be expected if the class that encapsulates the doSomething method is initialized on startup.